# How to get an image file from API in Symfony2

Tags: symfony-2.7

I would like to get an image from REST API by using `file_get_content()` and store in Symfony2.
`$image = file_get_contents('https://foobar, false, $context)`

But I am stacked when I am trying to sage the file.

`$image->move($app['config']['image_temp_realdir'], $filename);`

This line cause "Error: Call to a member function move() on string".
I understand this file data is not a File entity, but how can I convert this into File Entity? Or any method I can use to get file instead of `file_get_content()`?

Thanks in advance to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem resolved.

Saved the file by `file_put_contents()` and created new File.

`file_put_contents($app['config']['image_temp_realdir'].'/'.$filename, $image);
$file = new File($app['config']['image_temp_realdir'].'/'.$filename);`